# DbContext.Set<T>().SqlQuery Loading related entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am running the below code:

```
var paramUserId = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "userId",
    Value = userId
};

string query = string.Format("{0} {1}",
              "usp_GetItems",
              "@userId");

var results = _context.Set<Item>().SqlQuery(query, paramUserId);
```

The `usp_GetItems` is a stored procedure I have.
However my navigation properties are not being loaded. Is there anyway to acomplish this on Entity Framework?

Because according to this question [Eager loading in EntityFramework with DbContext.Database.SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136923/eager-loading-in-entityframework-with-dbcontext-database-sqlquery) looks like it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: No, this [doesn't seem possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581352/ef-4-1-dbcontext-sqlquery-and-include) with `SqlQuery`. Can you unwrap your stored proc back into navigable DbSets?

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035677/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-how-do-i-get-the-the-entity-to-hav

Comment: No, I am using a recursive CTE. Thanks

Comment: @PaulZahra The information on that question is from 2009. Is the answer up to date? Microsoft already release several improvements of EF, and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136923/eager-loading-in-entityframework-with-dbcontext-database-sqlquery it's possible.

Comment: Are you missing an @ sign in paramUserId.ParameterName?

Comment: @user910683 It's working this way. I guess the issue is not there :)

Comment: So when you have the results populated can't you just do an include to get the navigation properties?

Comment: Would that include the related entities of all records gathered from database on one shot?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Stored Proc returns a denormalization of `Items` and `Users`, one idea comes to mind is to use a projection DTO which mimics the structure of the results of the stored procedure, and then to use the [`Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) flavour of `SqlQuery` to project into a flattened DTO.

You can then use `LINQ` to again re-normalize the result set back into your entity graph, which I guess was the original intention.

**In Detail**

Assuming the existing entities from your EF Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Create a transfer DTO which represents the flattened structure of your Stored Proc result set:

```
public class UserItemProcDto
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then project into the denormalized DTO, and finally renormalize using LINQ:

```
var results = _context.SqlQuery<UserItemProcDto>(query, paramUserId);

var usersWithItems = results.GroupBy(r => r.UserId)
    .Select(g => new User
    {
        UserId = g.Key,
        Name = g.First().UserName,
        Items = g.Select(i => new Item
        {
            ItemId = i.ItemId,
            Name = i.ItemName
        }).ToList()
    });
```

This is obviously not something you would want to do for many stored procedures which span multiple tables, of course :)

Comment: One thing to note is that if there is a reverse entity navigation of `Item.User`, that you would likely need to do this as a second discrete step - AFAIK there is no way to link both references during the creation projection.